# Hypercomplex Numbers of the Form $a + ib$ Where $i^2 = p + iq$

Tags: abstract-algebra, hypercomplex-numbers

Recently, I've been interested in hypercomplex number systems, and I have come across the three main 2-dimensional algebras:
\begin{align*}
i^2 &= -1 \\
j^2 &= 1 \\
\varepsilon^2 & = 0
\end{align*}
I know that there are many more well-studied systems in higher dimensions, but I am more interested in basic two-dimensional algebras. These algebras would contain a single numbers with a single real part and imaginary part (multiplied by $i$) where
$$
i^2 = a + ib
$$
My question is why aren't the other possible number systems of this form as popular as the complex, split-complex, and dual numbers? $i^2 = k$ seems to hold similar properties to the other systems, and $i^2 = 1 + ik$ holds similar properties to the metallic means. Are the other systems not as useful as the complex numbers, etc., or do they just not hold basic properties that one would want an algebra to have?

Comment: This is one of those things where I'd encourage you to work out some of the properties of these hypercomplex numbers yourself. Exploring relatively untouched areas of mathematics is good fun.

Comment: Up to a change of coordinates the complex, split-complex, and dual numbers are actually the only possibilities, so you don't get anything new this way. This is worth working out as an exercise.

Comment: (Big hint: complete the square.)